# Architecture of specific ANN in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Can someone check did I guess correct number of neurons in input/hidden/output layer and overall params please.

My idea of this ANN:

Input neurons : 784 (28x28)
Hidden Layers : 1
Size of hidden layer(s) : 25
Activation function : Log-sigmoid
Training method : gradient descent
Data size : 400 + 200

There are 400 bmp images used for training of it, and 200 for checking (however only 1-50 get guessed with 100% rate and others 0% rate...)

```
clear all;
clc
for kk=1:400
    pl=ones(28,28);                     %³õÊ¼»¯28*28¶þÖµÍ¼ÏñÎªÈ«°×
    m=strcat('b',int2str(kk),'.bmp');   %Á¬½Ó×Ö·ûµÃµ½Ñù±¾ÎÄ¼þÃû
    x=imread(m,'bmp');                  %¶ÁÈëÑÐ±¾ÎÄ¼þÍ¼Ïñ
    pl=im2bw(x,0.5);                    %°ÑÑù±¾Í¼Ïñ×ª»¯Îª¶þÖµÍ¼
    for m=0:27                          %ÐÎ³ÉÉñ¾­ÍøÂçÊäÈëÏòÁ¿
        p(m*28+1:(m+1)*28,kk)=pl(1:28,m+1);
    end
end
%ÊÖÐ´ÌåÑù±¾¶ÔÓ¦µÄÊý×Ö£¨´Ób1.bmpµ½b400.bmp ¹²400¸ö£©£º
t=[5 0 4 1 9 2 1 3 1 4 3 6 3 6 1 7 2 8 6 9 4 0 9 1 1 2 4 3 2 7 8 8 6 9 0 5 6 0 7......
   6 1 8 7 9 3 9 8 5 9 3 3 0 7 4 9 8 0 9 4 1 4 4 6 0 4 5 6 1 0 0 1 7 1 6 3 0 2 1......
   1 7 8 0 2 6 7 8 3 9 0 4 6 7 4 6 8 0 7 8 3 1 5 7 1 7 1 1 6 3 0 2 9 3 1 1 0 4 9......
   2 0 0 2 0 2 7 1 8 6 4 1 6 3 4 1 9 1 3 3 9 5 4 7 7 4 2 8 5 8 6 0 3 4 6 1 9 9 6......
   0 3 7 2 8 2 9 4 4 6 4 9 7 0 9 2 7 5 1 5 9 1 2 3 1 3 5 9 1 7 6 2 8 2 2 6 0 7 4......
   9 7 8 3 2 1 1 8 3 6 1 0 3 1 0 0 1 1 2 7 3 0 4 6 5 2 6 4 7 1 8 9 9 3 0 7 1 0 2......
   0 3 5 4 6 5 8 6 3 7 5 8 0 9 1 0 3 1 2 2 3 3 6 4 7 5 0 6 2 7 9 8 5 9 2 1 1 4 4......
   5 6 4 1 2 5 3 9 3 9 0 5 9 6 5 7 4 1 3 4 0 4 8 0 4 3 6 8 7 6 0 9 7 5 7 2 1 1 6......
   8 9 4 1 5 2 2 9 0 3 9 6 7 2 0 3 5 4 3 6 5 8 9 5 4 7 4 2 7 3 4 8 9 1 9 2 1 7 9......
   1 8 7 4 1 3 1 1 0 2 3 9 4 9 2 1 6 8 4 7 7 4 4 9 2 5 7 2 4 4 2 1 9 2 2 8 7 6 9...... 
   8 2 3 8 1 6 5 1 1 0];
%´´½¨BPÍøÂç
pr(1:784,1)=0;
pr(1:784,2)=1;
t1=clock;                   %¼ÆÊ±¿ªÊ¼
%ÉèÖÃÑµÁ·²ÎÊý
net=newff(pr,[25 1],{'logsig','purelin'},'traingdx','learngdm');
net.trainParam.epochs=5000;             %ÉèÖÃÑµÁ·´ÎÊý
net.trainParam.goal=0.05;               %ÉèÖÃÐÔÄÜº¯Êý
net.trainParam.show=10;                 %Ã¿10ÏÔÊ¾
net.trainParam.Ir=0.05;                 %ÉèÖÃÑ§Ï°ËÙÂÊ
net=train(net,p,t);                     %ÑµÁ·BPÍøÂç
datat=etime(clock,t1)                   %¼ÆËãÉè¼ÆÍøÂçµÄÊ±¼äÎª66.417s
%Éú³É²âÊÔÑù±¾
pt(1:784,1)=1;                       
pl=ones(28,28);                         %³õÊ¼»¯28*28¶þÖµÍ¼ÏñÏñËØ
for kk=401:600
    pl=ones(28,28);                     %³õÊ¼»¯28*28¶þÖµÍ¼ÏñÎªÈ«°×
    m=strcat('b',int2str(kk),'.bmp');   %Á¬½Ó×Ö·ûµÃµ½Ñù±¾ÎÄ¼þÃû
    x=imread(m,'bmp');                  %¶ÁÈëÑÐ±¾ÎÄ¼þÍ¼Ïñ
    pl=im2bw(x,0.5);                    %°ÑÑù±¾Í¼Ïñ×ª»¯Îª¶þÖµÍ¼
    for m=0:27                          %ÐÎ³ÉÉñ¾­ÍøÂçÊäÈëÏòÁ¿
        pt(m*28+1:(m+1)*28,kk-400)=pl(1:28,m+1);
    end
end
[a,Pf,Af]=sim(net,pt);                  %ÍøÂç·ÂÕæ
a=round(a)                              %Êä³öÊ¶±ð½á¹û
%²âÊÔÑù±¾¶ÔÓ¦µÄÊý×Ö£¨´Ób401.bmpµ½b600.bmp ¹²200¸ö£©£º
tl=[2 6 4 5 8 3 1 5 1 9 2 7 4 4 4 8 1 5 8 9 5 6 7 9 9 3 7 0 9......
   0 6 6 2 3 9 0 7 5 4 8 0 9 4 1 1 8 7 1 2 6 1 0 3 0 1 1 8 2 0 3 9 4 0 5 0 6 1 7......
   7 8 1 9 2 0 5 1 2 2 7 3 5 4 4 7 1 8 3 9 6 0 3 1 1 2 0 3 5 7 6 8 2 9 5 8 5 7 4...... 
   1 1 3 1 7 5 5 5 2 5 8 2 0 9 7 7 5 0 9 0 0 8 9 2 4 8 1 6 1 6 5 1 8 3 4 0 5 5 8...... 
   3 4 2 3 9 2 1 1 5 2 1 3 2 8 7 3 7 2 4 6 9 7 2 4 2 8 1 1 3 8 4 0 6 5 9 3 0 9 2......
   4 7 1 1 9 4 2 6 1 8 9 0 6 6 7];
k=0;
for i=1:200
    if a(i)==tl(i)
        k=k+1;
    end
end
rate=1.00*k/200;                        %¼ÆËã×îºóÕýÈ·ÂÊÎª0.495
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for here.  Is this about the Neural Network Architecture, or is there an issue in the code that is generating unwanted results?  Could you please provide more information?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes Matthew, it is about Neural Networks. I have found this example at pudn and I wanted to see did I correctly understood the topology of NN (what are inputs and outputs etc). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong, since you don't specify the number of output neurons and the number of patterns per class in your dataset. However, it seems that you have created only one output neuron for your network. In this case, the network assings ALL patterns to the same class, and the classification accuracy you get is equal to the a priori probability. If, for example, the first 50 patterns of your dataset belong to the same class, and the rest to different classes, a classifier with one output will assign all patterns to the first class, so you will get the first 50 right.

If this is the case, you should create a classifier with N outputs, where N is the number of classes in your dataset. In this case, the classifier will vote for each class, and the pattern will be assigned to the class with the maximum output. If for example you have 3 classes, and the output for a specific pattern is [0.2, 0.83, 0.6], the pattern will be assigned to the second class.

Moreover, converting to image to black-and-white is probably not the best way. It would be better to convert the image to grayscale (to preserve the histogram to some extent), and use some normalization to compensate for differences in lighting.

Finally, keep in mind that neural networks essentially detect similarity between input vectors. So, if you need to classify pictures, you need to find a representation such that similar images produce similar input vectors. Feeding the values of the pixels into the classifier is not a such representation. For example, if you turn the image upside down, the input vector changes completely, even though it still shows the same object. You don't want that. You want features that depend on the object shown, and not on lighting/angle etc. However, extracting such features is a different matter altogether (for example see some examples for [image preprocessing](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/table_of_content_imgproc/table_of_content_imgproc.html#table-of-content-imgproc) and [feature extraction](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html#table-of-content-feature2d) from the OpenCV framework, the standard image processing and computer vision tool in C++/python)

If you are interested in neural networks and not image processing, it would be better to start with some standard classification problems from the [UCI repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) (eg. iris flower, wisconsin breast cancer) and practice with them until you produce good results and feel comfortable with the tools you are using.

Comment: And what about input neurons, 784 is correct or ? This isnt my design, its from some example on pudn.com. I will wait for you to modify answer, but you are 100% right, and I think you know alot about ANN because you guessed that first 50 images will be guessed right. This ANN has success rate of 25% +/- 0.1% :) when runned in MATLAB R2010a. I will accept answer tomorrow so I dont break your edit. PS bluenote from 'TheSting' ?

Comment: If you are feeding the pixels into the network, 28*28=784 is correct. However, it is generally not a good idea (i edited the answer for details). PS: "bluenote" from the blues guitar scale, I didn't remember the horse from the movie:)